# Android API 32 Sources not Found

Tags: android, android-studio

I am currently using Android Studio Arctic Fox and was trying to dig into the source code of several key Java classes in the Android API 32, however, it states that there are no packages found to download. Is the source for Android API 32 not available yet or is there a few steps I can take to get Android Studio to be able to look at the Java source code?

Comment: Sources are now available. Try again

Comment: Next time you can also check if the direct download link is available.
Search in the XML file https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository2-2.xml Here you have the links to all the sources for each API.
In your case https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sources-32_r01.zip

Answer (score 12):

As per documentation they didn't publish 32 yet. Check this -
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platforms

[image]

Answer (score 8):

32 is now published!

**Old Solution**

1. Open the app `build.gradle`
2. Change `compileSdk` to 31
3. Change `targetSdk` to 31

[image]

Go to the desired source and click the `download` button at the top (warning message).

[image]

Close the tab and open the source again.

[image]